# When and where can I buy alcohol in New Caledonia?

Tags: regulations, alcohol, new-caledonia

Supermarkets in New Caledonia have amazing selections of French wine and liquor, but half the time they seem to be roped off with "Closed" signs and I can't figure out the pattern: apparently 5 PM on  Wednesday is not allowed, but 10 AM on a Sunday is fine?!

So when exactly *can* a visitor buy a bottle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this, apparently, is the law since 2013 or so in Noumea and nearby:

- Supermarkets and other general stores must halt liquor sales at **12 noon** on **Friday, Saturday, Sunday and Wednesday**.  Selling in the morning is allowed, as is selling all day on Monday, Tuesday and Thursday.
- In addition, liquor may not be sold on the afternoon before a public holiday and all day during the public holiday.
- However, speciality wine retailers (*cavistes*) are exempted and can sell liquor <18%, but not beer.
- The duty-free shop at Tontouta airport is also exempt.
- All this applies only to take away: restaurants, bars and nightclubs  have no restrictions for alcohol consumed in premises.

Reference: http://www.nouvelle-caledonie.gouv.fr/Politiques-publiques/Alimentation-consommation-et-concurrence/Vente-d-alcool/Reglementation-vente-d-alcool

And if you're wondering "why!?", apparently the idea is to stop schoolchildren from picking up drinks after school ends (Wednesday is a half day).  Asking for ID when buying alcohol, however, doesn't seem to be a thing...

Also, the rules above apply to Noumea, but local *communes* have wide latitude to change them and many parts of the country are more or less dry.  (Alcohol abuse is widespread among in the Kanak community.)

Comment: In the 2nd bullet point, did you mean "on the afternoon before a public holiday and all day during the public holiday"?